# Summing Daily Sales Data between two ranges

Tags: excel, range, sumifs

We have been having this problem for a little while, but I know that once I figure out the solution it will save me loads of time. I have a data pull of sales from a chain of grocery stores with dates on top and products on the side. Shown here: [View of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIu78.png)

We would like to show sales for these products between specific date ranges. These ranges are shown for Current Year and Last Year. I tried the Last Year's sales with a sumif, but sadly that is the #VALUE that you see here: [Hopeful Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIOzX.png)

I thought this equation would solve my problem, but no: 
=SUMIFS(Input!B2:NB51,Input!A2:A51,Output!A2,Input!B1:NB1,">="&Output!D2,Input!B1:NB1,"<="&Output!E2)

Google Docs of the spreadsheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rdoGKliu3suu7mfDTB7Ckj83EzeZGmhw5yZnQ7u5X94/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because column array and row array are different and can't be used together in these formulas even if they have the same length.

You can use this formula at your Output F2 (close it with ctrl+shift+enter)

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("Input!"&ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,Input!A:A,0),MATCH(D2,Input!$1:$1,0))&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,Input!A:A,0),MATCH(E2,Input!$1:$1,0))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sheet Output

F2=SUMPRODUCT((Input!$A$2:$A$1000=Output!$A3)* (Input!$B$1:$ABA$1>=Output!D3)* (Input!$B$1:$ABA$1<=Output!E3)*(Input!$B$2:$ABA$1000))